# Error when acquiring a lock in julia 1.5.2

Tags: multithreading, locking, julia

I am following the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/) to acquire a lock on a variable but it fails:

```
a = 0
lock(a) do
    a += 1
end
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching lock(::var"#3#4", ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  lock(::Any, ::Base.GenericCondition) at condition.jl:78
  lock(::Any, ::Base.AbstractLock) at lock.jl:158
  lock(::Any, ::WeakKeyDict) at weakkeydict.jl:76
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[3]:1
```

The error message is clear but why would the code provided in the documentation fail. Moreover, not sure where to look for the detailed documentation about the `lock` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out:

```
a = 0
l = ReentrantLock()
lock(l) do
    global a # Needed if using REPL
    a += 1
end
```